# How to set top padding on image in fancyhead?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm using `fancyhdr`, with a simple logo like the one below.

[image]

With MWE like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% set the font of the document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[letterpaper, left=19mm, right=19mm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm, headheight=43.6pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{my-orange}{RGB}{238,113,43}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{my-style}{
    \fancyhf{} %Clear Everything.
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.75pt} 
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.75pt} 
    \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=5.15cm]{test_logo.png}}     
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{my-orange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
    \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{my-orange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}  
    \fancyfoot[C]{} 
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page | \thepage}
}

\pagestyle{my-style}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Compiling with XeLaTeX.

My problem is that the logo in the header is too close to the top of the page as follows:

[image]

I want to add padding so the logo is centred vertically within the header, is it possible to do this easily? Also should I want to artificially increase the length of the header how can I do that? I tried changing the `headheight` in `geometry`, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: "Length of the header row" references the (horizontal) width in my opinion, which has nothing to do with `headheight`. So what are you referring to exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\raisebox` to vertically move the image to the desired location; adjust the settings according to your needs:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% set the font of the document
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[letterpaper, left=19mm, right=19mm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm,headheight=34pt,headsep=15pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{my-orange}{RGB}{238,113,43}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{my-style}{
    \fancyhf{} %Clear Everything.
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.75pt} 
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.75pt} 
    \fancyhead[R]{\raisebox{-0.35\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=5.15cm]{test_logo.png}}}     
    \renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{my-orange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
    \renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{my-orange}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}  
    \fancyfoot[C]{} 
    \fancyfoot[R]{Page | \thepage}
}

\pagestyle{my-style}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- I changed the headheight to `29pt` (your value was too large for the current contents).
- To change the width for the header/footer or both you have the commands

  ```
  \fancyheadoffset
  \fancyfootoffset
  \fancyhfoffset
  ```

  Refer to the package documentation to see the synatx and examples of use.
- I added the `showframe` option to `geometry`, so you can have a visual guideline of the page layout.
- Change the vertical separation between the text and the header using the `headsep` option for geometry.
- Don't use `inputenc` nor `fontenc` with `fontspec`.

An explanation on `\raisebox`:

```
\raisebox{<length>}{<content>}
```

will move vertically (upwards for a positive length and downwards for a negative one) `<contents>`.

The extended syntax

```
\raisebox{<length1>}[<length2>][<length3>]{<content>}
```

allows to trick LaTeX to think the object to be moved has `height=<length2>`
and `depth=<length3>`. In my example code, LaTeX thinks is moving a box with `0pt` height and depth.

Comment: Could you explain a little in your answer what `raisebox` is and how it works in this instance please?

Comment: Also this eliminates padding on the bottom of the logo - as shown here - http://i.imgur.com/uajG5Ep.png - ideally I would like some padding below before the hrule as well.

Comment: @Bem For your second comment, change the `-0.5\height` value in `\raisebox` to the desired value.

Comment: Thanks, though I still can't seem to get `\fancyheadoffset`, `\fancyfootoffset`, or `\fancyhfoffset` to increase the heights of the header / footer, could you possibly show how those commands work please?

Comment: @Ben I added an explanation on `\raisebox`. As I said in my answer, those commands control the *width*, not the height (your question mentioned "length" so I thought you were referring to the width.). To control the height, use `headsep` and/or `headheight` as options to `geometry`.